# Getting dynamically rendered Vue.js dropdown to work with Select2 library

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jquery-select2

I am new to Vue so pardon me if this is an easy question. I have a page where I dynamically render a select dropdown and dynamically populate its options based on a computed property called **filteredWidgets** that depends on selections the user made in other dropdowns. The markup is as follows:

```
<div v-if="filteredWidgets.length > 0">
 <select id="widgetSelect" name="widgets">
      <option value="">Select up to two Widgets</option>
      <option v-for="widget in filteredWidgets" v-bind:value='widget.id'>
         @{{widget.name}}
      </option>
   </select>
</div>
```

From the Select2 documentation, it states that this is how you convert the select/option elements to become Select2 multiselect elements:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#widgetSelect').select2();
});
```

I can get this to work for a page with a non-dynamically rendered select dropdown. Obviously this doesn't work with Vue because the dropdown is rendered dynamically, and it is based on the computed property selectedWidgets. I need to find a way to get select2 to work at the time this dropdown appears/changes. Here is the computed property method filteredWidgets():

```
filteredWidgets() {
  var filteredWidgets = this.availableWidgets.filter(widget => {
     return widget.color == selectedColor && widget.size == selectedSize;
  });

  return filteredWidgets;
}
```

While the default select dropdown renders as I want it to and contains the filtered widgets I want, I need to figure out how to apply select2() to the widgetSelect dropdown immediately after it is rendered by Vue. What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`watch` for changes to `filteredWidgets`, and call `.select2()`.

```
watch: {
    async filteredWidgets() {
        await this.$nextTick() // wait for DOM to update
        $(this.$refs.widgetSelect).select2()
    }
}
```

You'll need to add a `ref` to the `<select>` so you can access the element directly with `this.$refs.widgetSelect`, instead of doing something like `this.$el.querySelector('#widgetSelect')`. The `id` attr is no longer needed, unless you're using it for something else.

```
<select ref="widgetSelect" name="widgets">
```

Comment: Thank you so much. If I can get this to work you'll get a check. So this watch function will be used in addition to the computed property function I outlined above, is that correct?

Comment: Yep, you can `watch` for changes to `computed` properties.